# Python with Tornado: How to get fetch response in async functions?

Tags: python, asynchronous, httpclient, tornado

I'm trying to create a Python script which running **Tornado Async http client with fetch** and trying to get the response and print the response.body to the screen.

my class code is:

```
class MyAsyncHTTPClient(httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient):

    @gen.coroutine
    def _fetch(self, url):

        print('send Asynchronous request ...['+url+"]   ")

        http_response = yield gen.Task(self.fetch, url)
        print(http_response.body)

        print('got Asynchronous response !!'+str(http_response))

        raise gen.Return(http_response.body)
```

and I'm calling it this way:

```
async_http_client = MyAsyncHTTPClient()
res_body = async_http_client._fetch(url)
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how to deal with this code to get the returned value once it's ready.
can you please help?
Thanks!

**Editing**

I have also tried implementing this function like:

```
class MyAsyncHTTPClient(httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient):
    @gen.coroutine
    def _fetch(self, url):
        print('send Asynchronous request ...['+url+"]   "+str(self))
        http_response = yield self.fetch(url)
        print('got Asynchronous response !!')
        return http_response.body
```

But I'm having the same results :(

**Editing again**

I have succeeded running the async class...but without the inherited object self. 
I did it like that:

```
@gen.coroutine
def _fetch_async(self, url):
    print('send Asynchronous request ...[' + url + "]   ")
    http_response = yield httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch(url)
    #http_response = yield self.fetch(url)
    print('got Asynchronous response !!')
    return http_response.body
```

and it worked fine.
The issue is that I need to use the inherited object self, and I'm not sure what am I missing here when defining the class.
When debugging I can see that self is very "thin" with its content..
Please let me know what am I doing wrong here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions can only be called from other asynchronous functions. You must call `_fetch` like this:

```
@gen.coroutine
def f():
    async_http_client = MyAsyncHTTPClient()
    res_body = yield async_http_client._fetch(url)
```

If you're not doing this in the context of a tornado server, the best way to call a coroutine from your `__main__` block is like this:

```
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().run_sync(f)
```

Comment: Also, don't subclass `AsyncHTTPClient`. There's no need to for what you're doing here, and that class is full of magic that will confuse you.

Comment: Thanks @Ben 
I have tried calling the function with yield (it's with coroutine also), but got an error:
ERROR:tornado.application:Exception in callback functools.partial(<function wrap.<locals>.null_wrapper at 0x106a6fae8>, <tornado.concurrent.Future object at 0x106a7ea90>)
...
http_response = yield gen.Task(self.fetch, url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1055, in run
    value = future.result()
  ...
.../httpclient.py", line 264, in fetch_impl
    raise NotImplementedError()
NotImplementedError

Comment: and in that case, I'm required to do that through a class. I will be more than happy if you can explain a little bit more about this case. thanks @Ben Darnell.

Comment: Like I said, AsyncHTTPClient is magic and subclassing it won't work unless you understand what's going on. I don't know what you're trying to accomplish here but you should be writing your own class that contains a reference to an AsyncHTTPClient instead of subclassing it.

Comment: @bendarmell Thanks a lot!
Could you please assist understanding this "magic" subclassing? (just for my knowledge) pointing me to a good tutorials would be great also :)

Comment: There are two parts to the magic: [tornado.util.Configurable](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/ccd4930b2fe17ecf13127c7fd31e51de64948d8e/tornado/util.py#L266) (especially its `__new__` method), which controls which class is actually instantiated, and then [AsyncHTTPClient has its own `__new__` method](https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/blob/ccd4930b2fe17ecf13127c7fd31e51de64948d8e/tornado/httpclient.py#L163) which tries to reuse existing instances if possible.

Comment: Thanks @Ben Darnell!